# Listing multiple arrays using a ForEach - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

**OUTLINE:**

I have a data model that contains an array of video names that are attached to each `ProductModel`.

So for example: `ProductModel` 1 would contain videos `video1`, `video2`. However, `ProductModel` 2 would contain videos `video3`, `video4` and `video5`. As well as the name of the videos I also have a thumbnail and description that link in with the video names.

My data model looks like this:

***NOTE:*** *There are other multiple ProductModels, but for the purpose of keeping the code short I have only shown one.*

```
struct ProductModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var video: [String]
    var videoThumbnail: [String]
    var videoDescription: [String]
}

let productData: [ProductModel] = [
    ProductModel(
        video: ["video1", "video2"],
        videoThumbnail: ["thumbnail1", "thumbnail2"],
        videoDescription: ["description1", "description2"]
    ),
    ProductModel(
        video: ["video3", "video4", "video5"],
        videoThumbnail: ["thumbnail3", "thumbnail4", "thumbnail5"],
        videoDescription: ["description3", "description4", "description5:]
    ),
]
```

**PROBLEM:**

When trying to list the arrays using a ForEach I keep getting errors. I have tried 2 different ways but I keep getting errors and can't see where I am going wrong. Any guidance would be appreciated.

*ForEach method 01:*

```
ForEach(0..<product.video.count){ item in
    Button(action: {
        // PLAY VIDEO
    }) {
        VStack{
            Image(product.thumbnail[item]) // VIDEO THUMBNAIL
            Text(product.video[item]) // VIDEO NAME
            Text(product.videoDescription[item]) // VIDEO DESCRIPTION
        }
    }
}
```

*ForEach method 02:*

```
ForEach(Array(zip(product.video, product.videoThumbnail, product.videoDescription)), id: \.0) { item in
    Button(action: {
        // PLAY VIDEO
    }) {
        VStack{
            Image(item.1) // VIDEO THUMBNAIL
            Text(item.0) // VIDEO NAME
            Text(item.2) // VIDEO DESCRIPTION
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your model. Having "associated" arrays often causes problems. Rather have a single array of a `Video` struct that has `name`, `description` and `thumbnail` properties.then you can just use `ForEach(product.videos ...`

Comment: The above comment is almost certainly the right path to take. In the meantime, your first example should work in the most general sense if you just fix a typo -- you have `thumbnail` but the correct property is `videoThumbnail`. But, in general using ForEach with indices like this isn't a great plan.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, just missed the typo! Could you please explain what you mean with a single array of a `Video` struct?

Comment: `ProductModel` should have a property `var videos:[Video]`. The `Video` struct has the three properties I mentioned in my first comment. This replaces the three arrays you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
///This way relies on the index for the videos and related info always matching. It is an easy way to have mixmatch information
struct NestedList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(0..<productData.count, id: \.self){ productsIdx in
                ForEach(0..<productData[productsIdx].video.count, id: \.self){ videoIdx in
                    Button(action: {
                        print(
                            "playing" + productData[productsIdx].video[videoIdx])
                    }, label: {
                        HStack{
                            Text(productData[productsIdx].videoThumbnail[videoIdx])
                            Text(productData[productsIdx].videoDescription[videoIdx])
                        }
                    })
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The more concise way to do this is to isolate the video information to a model so it all sticks together regardless of the order. As mentioned in the comments.

```
struct ProductModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var videos: [VideoModel]
}
struct VideoModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var video: String
    var videoThumbnail: String
    var videoDescription: String
}
var productData: [ProductModel]{
    var videos : [VideoModel] = []
        for n in 1...6{
            videos.append(VideoModel(video: "video\(n)", videoThumbnail: "thumbnail\(n)", videoDescription: "description\(n)"))
        }
    return [ProductModel(videos: videos)]
}
struct NestedList2: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(productData, id: \.id){ product in
                ForEach(product.videos, id: \.id){ video in
                    Button(action: {
                        print(
                            "playing" + video.video)
                    }, label: {
                        HStack{
                            Text(video.videoThumbnail)
                            Text(video.videoDescription)
                        }
                    })
                    
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `for` loop is just to automate the creation of the array. The first variable below is interchangeable with your `productData` and the second shows the equivalent to the build format of the array with the new structure.

```
var productData: [ProductModel]{
    var videos: [String] = []
    var thumbnails: [String] = []
    var descriptions: [String] = []
    for n in 1...6{
        videos.append("video\(n)")
        thumbnails.append("thumbnail\(n)")
        descriptions.append("description\(n)")
    }
    
    return [ProductModel(video: videos, videoThumbnail: thumbnails, videoDescription: descriptions)]
}
    let productData: [ProductModel] = [ProductModel(videos: [
        VideoModel(video: "video1", videoThumbnail: "thumbnail1", videoDescription: "description1"),
        VideoModel(video: "video2", videoThumbnail: "thumbnail2", videoDescription: "description2"),
        VideoModel(video: "video3", videoThumbnail: "thumbnail3", videoDescription: "description3"),
        VideoModel(video: "video4", videoThumbnail: "thumbnail4", videoDescription: "description4"),
        VideoModel(video: "video5", videoThumbnail: "thumbnail5", videoDescription: "description5"),
        VideoModel(video: "video6", videoThumbnail: "thumbnail6", videoDescription: "description6")
    ])]
```

Different ways of accomplishing a sample array the loop has less copy and paste .

You would create your own `[VideoModel]` using the method that most benefits your use case.

Comment: Thanks, this all makes sense except the `var videos:`?. As it is in a `for` loop I don't understand how I would add the different values to go into `video`, `videoThumbnail` & `videoDescription`. My model also other values that I am using elsewhere so would like to keep it all in one if possible.

Comment: See above. It is just an easy way to create an array. You would populate the array in th way that is best for your use case. If I answered your question please accept the answer above.

Comment: Maybe I am getting lost here, but each ProductModel will have multiple videos not just one video per model. So for example, the first ProductModel will have 4 videos and then the second may only have 2 videos, I have updated the outline in my question so it makes more sense, will this method still work?